# Sticky element inside a scrollable parent with fixed width

Tags: html, css

I have a scrollable container of a fixed width. Inside there is a containing element with a bunch of children with the first one being sticky.

```css
.scrollable {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.containing {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky {
 position: sticky;
 left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="containing">
    <div class="sticky">Sticky</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue I am facing if that the sticky element goes off the screen too soon (mid-way in my example). I understand that this happens because the width of the containing element is automatically set to 100% of its parent (i.e. 200px in my example) so it kinda meets the opposite side of the containing block.

Is there a way to set the width of the containing block relative to its parent real width (i.e. 200px + everything hidden by the scroll area) without having to specify this width explicitly? CSS solution only would be great.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what 'too soon' means here? Do you want sticky to disappear eventually rather than remaining stuck? If not then just remove the width: setting from .containing.

Comment: @AHaworth since the width of the sticky child is less than 200px of the scrollable parent, it should always be stuck. It is not in my example above. It moves off the screen once. you scroll 200px left. Removing width from the containing element doesn't solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice that if you manually set the width of the `.container` to a much higher value, the sticky will remain stuck until that value is reached. The problem is you then might have a lot of white space after your contents.

To make this work you need your `.containing` div to have the same width as its contents, and usually the solution is to set it as `inline-block` display. But you want `flex` display. Easy! Use `inline-flex`.

Here's your snippet with the change and you'll see it's working.

```css
.scrollable {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 200px;
}

.containing {
display: inline-flex;
}

.sticky {
 position: sticky;
 left: 0;
 background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="containing">
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="sticky">Sticky</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
    <div class="other">Other</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a nice idea. Breaks my layout, however is something I can work with. Thanks!

Comment: How exactly does it break your layout?

Comment: Oh, that's irrelevant to this issue. It's a complex table with sticky elements in two directions and collapsible elements. `inline-flex` breaks it somewhere, however I can fix that myself I think.